# Can't drag anymore or go back after dragging popup under the topbar

Tags: bug, top-bar, popup

The close/flag popups can be dragged from their title.

But after dragging a close popup under the new top bar, I can't drag it back anywhere. And I can't "return to previous page" with the mouse anymore.

[image]

Sure, there are plenty workarounds, like using keyboard shortcuts, or not dragging there in the first place, or refreshing the page, etc.

But allowing to drag in any situation may be nice:

- either putting the z-index of the popup higher than the top-bar
- either allowing dragging from the bottom of the popup too

Comment: You can click outside of the dialog and it goes away, so you can "return to previous page" with the mouse... Still just another workaround though.